# Pandas, summing across rows, dependent upon column content

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a weird Dataframe that is set up in the following manner:

```
header_one | header_two | header_three | header_four | to_sum_one | to_sum_two
     4             5            1              2       header_one   header_three
     2             4            10             12      header_two   header_four
```

Is there a way for me to create a new column by summing the columns indicated the in the sum_one and sum_two fields? For example, the first entry would add up to 5 since we want to sum to_sum_one (4) and to_sum_three (1)

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you can using `lookup` here

```
df.lookup(df.index,df.to_sum_one)+df.lookup(df.index,df.to_sum_two)
Out[282]: array([ 5, 16], dtype=int64)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, and it worked! Thank you so much for this I was struggling for quite a bit trying to find a solution

Answer (score 1):

I would try to use an apply, since it's the simplest way you can use this, just get the parameters you need as .value and use them in an insert.

Also, so you don't get mixed up in the arguments I would create a function that gets the sum params and use that.

There's probably a better way to do this but it might help.

```
    header_one | header_two | header_three | header_four | to_sum_one | to_sum_two
         4             5            1              2       header_one   header_three
         2             4            10             12      header_two   header_four


def sum(param1, param2):
     return df.param1+ df.param2
```

Then insert:

```
df.insert(6, "Sum", sum(df.to_sum_one, df.to_sum_two))
```

That's how I would do it. Let me know if it works.

Comment: This one worked as well actually, however W-B has the pandas in-house solution

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html#pandas.DataFrame.assign)?

`assign(**kwargs)`  *Assign new columns to a DataFrame, returning a new object (a copy) with the new columns added to the original ones.*

This seems to be what you want.